# Unpacking variables using lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x

Additional context:

```
    while True:
        Surface = input(Fmt.cleaveSurface).split('-');print('\n')
        if Surface != [''] and (len(Surface) == 2): 

            [
            self.cleaved.update({i + 1 : [*layers[i]]}) 
            for i in range(int(Surface[0]),int(Surface[1])+1)
            ]

        else: print('Exiting...\n'); raise SystemExit

        for i in range(len(self.cleaved)):
            if self.format == 'Abinit':
                cellSort = sorted(self.cleaved.items(), 
                    key = lambda x:(x[1][0],x[1][self.sortBy[0]]));
                print(Fmt.abinit.format(*cellSort[i][1][1:4],cellSort[i][1][0]))

            if self.format in ['','Quantum']:
                cellSort = sorted(self.cleaved.items(), 
                    key = lambda x: (x[1][self.sortBy[0]],x[1][self.sortBy[1]],x[1][self.sortBy[2]]))
                print(Fmt.quantum.format(*cellSort[i][1]))

        netCharge = int(sum([self.charges.get(data[0], 'Null') for data in self.cleaved.values()]));
```

I want to clean this statement up:

```
layeredCell = sorted(cell.items(), 
key = lambda x:(x[1][self.sortBy[0]],x[1][self.sortBy[1]],x[1][self.sortBy[2]]))
```

Here is an example of the format of self.cleaved:

```
{ 2: ['O', 0.01, -0.8, -0.195], 3: ['Pb', -0.251, -0.574, -0.1135],     ...
```

`self.sortBy` is a list of some permutation of 1,2,3 which dictates sorting order for self.cleaved

Example: `sortBy = [3,1,2]`
I'm not sure what syntax I need to be using as far as unpacking operator goes, but I'm guessing it would it be something similar to `*[x[1][*self.sortBy[:3]]`?

Comment: you could just try it and see if it throws an error. please also read [mre] and share a sample input and expected output so that others can help

Comment: what type is `x`?

Comment: Its going to depend on what `x[1]` is and what `self.sortBy[:3]` returns. It may be `lambda x: [x[1]] + self.sortBy[:3]]`. Or perhaps `[x[1], *self.sortBy[:3]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do something like this using list comprehension

```
key = lambda x: tuple(x[1][self.sortBy[i]] for i in range(3))
```

Comment: you can skip extra parenthesis and start index in range: `lambda x: tuple(x[1][self.sortBy[i]] for i in range(3))`